# javascript grab part of a string after a . (dot)

Tags: javascript, string, substr

I'm unable to read regex.

Let's say we have this string: "mydomain.bu.pu" and I want to grab the ".bu.pu" part of it;

I'm thinking about using something like:

indexOf and later substr ... But I confess I'm kind of lost...

Any help please? :D

Thanks in advance,
MEM

Comment: Thank you all... I was here... substring(indexOf(.),inputFieldValue.length);

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
var afterDot = str.substr(str.indexOf('.'));
```

Answer (score 12):

The above answers include the dot in the string. If you only want what's after the dot:

```
var afterDot = str.substr( str.indexOf('.') + 1 );
```

Answer (score 9):

```
s = s.substring(s.indexOf("."));
```

That should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the three simple way I know.

```js
const text = "Allah is great. Allah is only one"
const methodOne = text.split('.');
console.log(methodOne[0]); // BEFORE DOT
console.log(methodOne[1]);

const methodTwo = text.slice(text.indexOf('.')+1);
console.log(methodTwo);


const methodThree = text.substring(text.indexOf(".")+1);
console.log(methodThree)
```

Answer (score 0):

sixCommaTwoValidation method for numeric 6,2 validation and restiction.

```
    var afterDot = '';
    var beforeDots = inputValue.split('.'); 
    var beforeDot = beforeDots[0];
    if(beforeDots[1]){
        var afterDot = beforeDots[1];
        if(afterDot.length > 3 ){
             afterDot = afterDot.slice(0, 2);               
        }
        afterDot = '.'+ afterDot;

    }
    if(beforeDot){                  
        if(beforeDot.length > 6 ){          
            beforeDot = beforeDot.slice(0, 6);                      
        }
        if(beforeDots[1] == ''){
            beforeDot = beforeDot + '.';
        }
    }
    inputValue = beforeDot + afterDot;
    return inputValue;
```

Comment: We can use javascript grab part of a string after and before a . (dot)

Answer (score -1):

maybe this is too late to consider, but this codes works fine for me using jquery

```
var afterDot = value.substr(value.lastIndexOf('_') + 1);
```

> 1. lkjasdf_alksjd_ksdf.jpg = ksdf.jpg
> 2. aaa_bbb_ccc.jpg = ccc.jpg
> 3. testing_image.jpg = image.jpg

You could just replate '_' to '.'

Comment: `String.substr` is not standard and is deprecated. Use `String.substring` instead